# Do I have to use "eject" in terminal to load a cd/dvd (on Sony Vaio with eject button)

Tags: 11.10, dvd, vaio, sony, eject

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Sony Vaio VGN-AR61M as a dual boot machine (I have to keep windows for the CAD stuff I need for work).

After looking at different answers on why my eject button won't work the only remedy I can find is that I have to use the "eject" command in a terminal window which seems quaint to say the least. Is there a way to fix the button to work on the Vaio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's broken? Neither my DVD or Bluray eject buttons work if anything has their contents open (read: Nautilus viewing files, Totem playing something from it).

I find clicking the eject icon in Nautilus usually works if the button doesn't.

If you find that only using the eject command works perhaps you could just [write a little launcher](http://shuffleos.com/3274/how-to-create-desktop-launchers-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/) that runs `gksu eject /dev/sr...` so ejecting is just a double-click away. Or if you're using Unity, create a launcher for ejecting (if there isn't one already - I'm not a Unity user so I'm not sure).

Comment: The eject button is not broken it will not eject cd/dvd tray if I press the eject button on the laptop (it works under Win 7). I can't put a cd/dvd in the tray unless I open the terminal and type in the eject command. There must be a way of getting 11.10 to recognize and use the built in eject button (?). It's not like the button is cutting edge technology which makes me hopeful that there must be a fix. I have all the latest updates installed.

Comment: I'm not saying the button is physically broken, just that there may be software circumstances (it being "busy") that are making Ubuntu ignore the button press.

Comment: Thanks for your replies Oli, very much appreciated...I have tried to create a button/launcher to eject using the terminal after installing "Gnome Panel". What would be the address for the cd/dvd ? I put in "cdda://" and I got the message couldn't find address. I am a newb to Ubuntu and want to use it with my 3D app Blender and wish to import about 5 yrs worth of Blender files from my back-up discs cds and DVds. I thought Blender was hard to crack with a steep learning curve.